# Can I use time machine with a network drive?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, network-shares

How do I make Time Machine backup to a network drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, according to:

- http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=5918065
- http://www.flokru.org/2008/02/29/time-machine-backups-on-network-shares-in-leopard/
- http://blog.itoph.com/2008/02/using-leopard-time-machine-with-network.html

essentially, you have to:

```
% defaults write com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes 1
```

then your network shares should show up in the time machine interface.

Comment: When I try and connect to the share drive it comes up with this error:  OSStatus error 68

Comment: @thelearner Are you sure that wasn't an error -68? (read verify compare failed.) I cannot find error 68. What is the format of the network drive? If it's not HFS+ it won't work.