# Good automatic backup tool

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, backup

I am in search of a good backup tool that can backup to a network drive (because time machine cannot).

I want to be able to choose the folders I want to backup and then it does it every night on a schedule

Comment: timemachine can write to network folders, see my answer at http://superuser.com/questions/158049

Comment: Seconded.  Time Machine can backup to a network share.  Mine is backing up as I type this.  :)

Comment: please don't use the tag [mac-os] for Mac OS X questions.  use [osx] for that.  [mac-os] is for legacy Mac OS -- System 9 and earlier.

Comment: OK will do.  I am now able to see the shares however when I try and connect I get this error:  OSStatus error 68

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a cron script with [rsync](http://www.egg-tech.com/mac_backup/).

Comment: rsync is great for this. I would recommend the latest version of rsync, rather than the one provided by Apple, in order to copy metadata properly. Read [this article](http://www.bombich.com/mactips/rsync.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using http://tarsnap.com/, if you need encrypted backup somewhere in the cloud.